# INotifyPropertyChanged does't work when field of property change internally

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, field

I try to binding textblock usercontrol with property of my class, but it only works at initial stage, I have implement IPropertyChnaged in my class.

In my class, _Feedbackpos (field of property) would change in background, I don't know how to solve this problem.

my class

```
public class TestControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
  {
     if(PropertyChanged != null)
     {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
     }
  }

  private double _Feedbackpos;
  public double Feedbackpos
  {
     get 
     {
       return _Feedbackpos;
     }
     set
     {
       _Feedbackpos = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("Feedbackpos");
     }
  }

  //it's a callback function, it would excute when detect feedback position of controller change
  private void ReadFeedbackpos()
  {
    _Feedbackpos = Controller.Read();
  }

}
```

application windows

```
TestControl TestDll = new TestControl();

Binding BindingTxtBlk = new Binding(){Source= TestDll, Path = new Property("Feedbackpos")};

FeedbackPosTxtBlk.Setbinding(Textblock.TextProperty,BindingTxtBlk);
```

Comment: "*but it only works at initial stage*" please define this statement

Comment: You should use the property `Feedbackpos` to set the value, not the field if you want the property changed event to be raised.

Comment: Well if you aren't calling the `Setter` of the `Property`, how do you expect that the code inside the `Setter` will get executed?

Comment: FYI - `NotifyPropertyChanged("Feedbackpos");` isn't limited to be called inside the `Setter` you can call it anywhere you want, so you could extend your `ReadFeedbackpos` by simply calling `NotifyPropertyChanged("Feedbackpos");`

Comment: there is no _magic_ in `C#`. If you don't call `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));` - `PropertyChanged` event will not be rised.

Comment: Thanks guys, I fix the problem, and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function `ReadFeedbackpos()` to

```
private void ReadFeedbackpos()
{
    Feedbackpos = Controller.Read();
}
```

Otherwise `NotifyPropertyChanged("Feedbackpos");` will never get called.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works after I change _Feedbackpos to Feedbackpos in ReadFeedbackpos() and put NotifyPropertyChanged into ReadFeedbackpos().

Comment: @JFChang could you mark this as the answer if it's working for you? Thanks :-)